# Sending Emoji in Push Notifications via Node js on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am using apn module to send push to ios. It is working fine. But now I want to send emojis in push notifications.

```js
var apns = require('apn');

var options = {
    cert: 'abc.pem',                       
    certData: null,                                
    key: 'abc.pem',                       
    keyData: null,                                 
    passphrase: 'xyz',                              
    ca: null,                                      
    pfx: null,                                     
    pfxData: null,                                 
    gateway: 'gateway.push.apple.com',     
    port: 2195,                                    
    rejectUnauthorized: true,                      
    enhanced: true,                                                      
    cacheLength: 100,                              
    autoAdjustCache: true,                         
    connectionTimeout: 0,
    ssl: true
}

var message=req.body.post; // if I give a static value like message=\ud83d, it works fine
var deviceToken = new apns.Device(iosDeviceToken);
var apnsConnection = new apns.Connection(options);
var note = new apns.Notification();

note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; 
note.badge = 1;
note.sound = 'ping.aiff';
note.alert = message;

apnsConnection.pushNotification(note, deviceToken);
```

If I send what comes from form field, I see \ud83d in the phone. If I send \ud83d           from server, I see Emoji on the phone. What to do to get emojis on phone by getting it from form.

Comment: Can you show us where you're getting `req.body.post` from?

Comment: Did you find an answer to it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [iOS emoji codes](http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/).

Example: For victory hand emoji in node js:

```
notification.alert = 'This is a test notification \u270C';
```